# Does ruby 1.9.2 fully supports rails 2.3.x projects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, osx-lion

ruby 1.8.7 [does not compile well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734344/bug-bus-error-ruby-1-8-7) under Lion and Xcode 4.2. I'd like to know whether **ruby 1.9.2-p290** fully supports **rails 2.3.5** and/or **2.3.11**?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Rails 2.3.8 or Rails 2.3.10 fully compatible with Ruby 1.9.2? (any reference or source say that?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021037/is-rails-2-3-8-or-rails-2-3-10-fully-compatible-with-ruby-1-9-2-any-reference)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's more a question if Rails is supported on Ruby 1.9.2 - but yes, it should run fine on Ruby 1.9.2 - also you need to ensure that Gems you are intending to run work on both Rails 2.3.x and Ruby 1.9.x which will be down to each gem individually.

Answer (score 1):

There were some problems with the new encoding features in 1.9.2 in some older versions of rails. You should use the newest version of rails 2.3.x also for security reasons...

Answer (score 1):

Another (slightly older) resource for checking out whether your associated gems might work is [IsItRuby19](http://isitruby19.com/). It hasn't been getting as much traffic as it did in the past, but when assessing whether Rails 2.x apps would work on 1.9.x Ruby, it might help flesh out the rest of your stack. It has a few notes about the Rails gem set-proper (somewhat stale), and some current notes about many other common gems.

Might save some research time or get pointers before tracking down lots of release notes.